# In editing content, can I show source formatted HTML

Tags: wysiwyg, nodes

Might there be a way to show properly formatted HTML when in CKeditor's `source` view? Is there a way to color code the HTML and Javascript source for my more advanced content editors?

I have turned on Apply Source Formatting which has helped some.

Answer (score 1):

Syntax highlighting is your keywords.  I uncovered this for you.
http://code.google.com/p/ckeditor-syntaxhighlight/wiki/Installation

There is most likely more plugins available but you will need to add a plugin to achieve what you are looking for.